# Docker tomcat scale with loadbalancer

Tags: docker, tomcat, cluster-computing

I would like to implements docker-compose for my tomcat application where I can scale all tomcat containers that I need.

Does anyone can share with any docker-compose.yml example in order to see how configure it?

Thanks.